# difference between alternative syntax of header() with exit

Tags: php, syntax, header

I m curious to know that is there any diffrence between

```
header('Location:index.php'); // using  capital  `L`
exit(); // using parenthesis
```

**AND**

```
header('location:index.php');
exit;
```

which one we should recommend to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the actual [RFC for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30), you should use an uppercase "L", and an absolute URI:

```
header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php');
```

As far as `exit` vs `exit()`, there is no difference. It is a language construct, not a function, and the parenthesis are optional. You may even use `exit 0` or `exit(0)`.

Comment: Section 4.2 says that field names are case-insensitive. However, it's conventional to use initial capitals.

Comment: Whitespace after the colon is also preferred, but not required. Again, read section 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between exit; and exit();

and the Location should be written with a capital `L`